# jquery mousemove event with iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Mousemove event stops working when the cursor enters on iframe:
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/zt7avdx1/)

```
$(document)
  .on('mousemove', function(event) {
     console.log(event)
  })
```

is it possible to follow the cursor when it is on iframe area?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect mousemove when over an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645485/detect-mousemove-when-over-an-iframe)

Answer (score 2):

Found solution, add css attribute:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/zt7avdx1/1/)

Comment: I am not sure that this is a real solution... pointer-evets:none - prevent to (for example) click on iframe, youtube or vimeo iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function (event) {
    console.log( event.target.tagName + ': ' + event.type);
});
```

or:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {
        console.log( event.target.tagName + ': ' + event.type);
    });
});
```

Your problem in: `$(document).on('mousemove', function (event) {` is:

the event is executed before the dom is ready or the window is loaded.