# Splitter does not work with <iframe> or <object>

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mouseevent, splitter

I have a splitter by flexbox that works quite well ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8XLT4QRtuCkI7Mb9nOMW?p=preview)): users could drag the splitter easily, even though it is very thin. And the movement of the splitter is quite smooth without jumping. Additionally, the code is light.

However, it has trouble with `<iframe>` or `<object>` (a [new plunker with a iframe](https://plnkr.co/edit/l4Kwn5SCStEkBqRcZnHI?p=preview)). When we drag the part of the splitter near the iframe **quickly to the right**, we will see the mouse is not `<->` anymore, but becomes a normal mouse icon over the iframe.

I added `console.log(e.pageX)` in `script.js`. It shows that for the above case, this number does not update well. So does anyone have an alternative for that?

Otherwise, does anyone have a global solution for my splitter?

Splitters are everywhere, but it is hard to find a complete solution of a splitter that is thin and smooth to drag... Does anyone have any suggestion?

PS: Chrome version: Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit); macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: A flex item, by default, cannot be smaller than the size of its content (`min-width: auto`). In your first plunkr, there's no content. So the splitter can size down to 0 width. But in your second plunkr, the splitter must stop shrinking at the width of the iframe. ***Solution:*** *Add `min-width: 0` to `.col`.*

Comment: thank you, but that solves another problem... while dragging the splitter and moving the mouse on the iframe, you will see the problem of this thread...

Comment: You mean that the splitter moves with just the mouse movement?

Comment: Neither plunkr works at all in Firefox; you might want to look into that as well.

Comment: @Michael_B I added more details about how to reproduce the problem...

Comment: Testing in Chrome. Not getting that problem at all. No mouse changes. No splitter changes. Everything works the same at all times. (That's why I offered the solution in my first comment. It was the only "problem" I could see.)

Comment: @MrLister indeed, the splitter does not work at all in Firefox or Safari. But let's keep this question for this problem, though I am eager for a complete splitter solution for all the browsers...

Comment: @Michael_B I use `Chrome version: Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit); macOS Sierra 10.12.3`, and you?

Comment: Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 PC

Comment: @Michael_B I still see obvious problem on my side... we will see if other people can see the problem...

Comment: Add javascript tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this thread and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11865037/702977), which is a light solution. I have assigned an id `myiframe` to the frame, and added in `mousedown`:

```
$('#myiframe').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

then in `mouseup`:

```
$('#myiframe').css('pointer-events', 'all');
```

And here is [a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FP6z8ZVPthlTBIHyXaYj?p=preview).