# css3 transform: translatex(-100%); not working properly in IE11 & Edge

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

The container `transform: translatex(-100%);` moving to `transform: translatex(0);` in Internet Explorer 11 and Edge not working properly. Content moves but it goes back when touch on mouse.

```
.widget {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  max-height: 400px;
  left: 0;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
}
.widget:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transform: translatex(0);
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEMKKL

Comment: Try to use prefix `-ms-` for the transform property.

Comment: Like this  " -ms-transform: translatex(-100%);"

Comment: I think IE11 & Edge do not required prefixes even though I use autoprefixer

Comment: what do you mean by ` not working properly` . the transform works in IE

Comment: @MihaiT transformed content goes back to previous status before translation finishing

Comment: That is IEs behaviour. Two workarounds, one is setting `pointer-events:none` on the iframe but then it acts only as a screenshot (*you cannot interact with it*) or you [bubble the event your self](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442439/128165) but then the iframe's url cross-domain policy allows it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously, you will need to add a prefix of -ms- for browser support.

For reference, you can use: https://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: IE11 & Edge do not required prefixes even though I use autoprefixer

Comment: prefix `-ms-transform:  translatex(-100%); /* IE 9 */` above ie9 doesn't require prefix

Comment: If you add the prefix and inspect element, does it cross out transform and use -ms-transform?

Comment: I use `autoprefixer` which does all the prefix jobs