# How can I pause a jQuery on mouse hover iFrame object?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a jQuery that on mouse move it fade in/fade out a `div` object, however it doesn't work correctly when on view there is an `iframe`.

This is my jQuery:

```
var timer, myDiv = $('#mydiv');
$(document).on('mousemove', function(ev) {
    var _self = $(ev.target);

    clearTimeout(timer);

    if (_self.attr('id') === 'mydiv' || _self.parents('#mydiv').length) {
        return;
    }    

    if(!myDiv.hasClass('show')) {
       myDiv.fadeIn();
    }          

    timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        myDiv.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            myDiv.removeClass('show');
        });
    }, 1960);    
});
```

Why this jQuery doesn't work when the mouse pointer is hover an `iframe` object?

Here the [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/res8ymp6/2/)

You can see on top of the demo page the proper functioning of the jQuery, it display the red square on mouse movement and hide it after n seconds of inactivity.

Instead if you try to do the same but on the `iframe`, the red square become hidden and nothing else.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to *A. Wolff* that shown me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261328/receive-mousemove-events-from-iframe-too) I know that the solution is more complex than thought.

> If the documents are not on the same document.domain it becomes quite
>   a bit mroe complex, and you will need the iframes page to run
>   javascript itself that sets the mousemove event listener. and then you
>   can do cross frame communication as described here:
>   http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

The `iFrame` is referred to my subdomain page, so I can edit in any way needed.

How could I proceed?

Comment: `doesn't work` isn't a very descriptive problem statement. Please elaborate on relationship between div and iframe and give better explanation of the problem. A demo would definitely help

Comment: as @charlietfl mentioned, this doesn't explain much. can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @charlietfl the iframe is on background (100% in height and width) the mydiv is above this iframe in a small portion...Ok I'll try to make a fiddle

Comment: "How can I pause a jQuery ... ?" How can anyone pause a jQuery? The concept of pausing a jQuery needs to be explained.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 on mouse movement...indeed my jQuery works with a timer

Comment: @Sushil I'll make a fiddle!

Comment: Could be duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261328/receive-mousemove-events-from-iframe-too

Comment: @A.Wolff yes it's that I think...how to configure the listener on external domain?

Comment: @Simone External domain? Do you you mean cross domain iframe? If ya, your only solution i guess would be to use CSS `pointer-events: none;` on the iframe (or setting a transparent element as a DIV above the iframe for older browsers support) but this will disable all interaction with the iframe.

Comment: @A.Wolff from the best answer:"you will need the iframes page to run javascript itself that sets the mousemove event listener" I was talking about this...I need interaction of the iframe and it's not a problem to edit the page because I need to iframe a portion of my subdomain

Comment: @Sushil I added the demo to my question

Comment: @charlietfl I added the fiddle to my question

Comment: can set `document.domain` inside iframe to match main domain which allows script access from parent window

Comment: @charlietfl could you please show an example or add your answer perhaps?

Comment: have you tried enclosing the iframe in a div and giving the div a mousemove event?

Comment: @Sushil I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: @Simone can you try this fiddle and let me know if this is what you're looking at? i just added borders to see both the objects clearly. http://fiddle.jshell.net/res8ymp6/1/

Comment: @Sushil no, it's not...try this [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/res8ymp6/2/) . At the top you can see the correct working and what it's wrong when you are hover the iframe

Comment: You can post message from iframe to the parent window and handle it like in following example: http://jsfiddle.net/gcgx58dc/2

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried to add my `iframe` tag right after the `<body>\ `. Is it correct? Because if you use the mouse only inside the iframe, the jQuery doesn't work

Comment: @Simone The posted jsFiddle sample was to demonstrate how you should ( inside **your iframe** ) post message to parent window. If you don't have access to iframe source code, to allow it to post message, you are out of luck.  So add inside your iframe source code: `window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
window.parent.postMessage({pageX: e.pageX, pageY: e.pageY}, "*");
}, false);` And listen to it in parent window using: `$(window).on('message', function (m) {
    var e = jQuery.Event("mousemove", {
        target: $('#divFrame').get(0)
    });
    MouseOver(e, true);
});`

Comment: @A.Wolff A BIG hug to you, it works...thank you :)